# How to switch class for div using js?

Tags: javascript

I've done this using jquery, but can't do it with js.

Look at my code:

https:// jsfiddle. net/88pd6zj0/

It's working only with first class = "html", but not working with another.
I've tried change "querySelector" on "querySelectorAll" - and it's working no one class.

How to fix this problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: Edit the link pls.. and add the relevant code to the question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/88pd6zj0/

Comment: suraj meant that you need to take the code you put on JSFiddle and add it to your question with an [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Try document.querySelectorAll()

```js
var icon = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons div");
for(i =0;i<icon.length;i++){
icon[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){

 event.preventDefault();
 this.classList.add("active");
});
}
```

```css
.html, .html5, .css{
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 border:1px dashed;
  display:inline;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.active{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
 <div class="html ">
   <a href="#">HTML</a>
 </div>
 <div class="html5" >
   <a href="#">HTML 5</a>
 </div>
 <div class="css">
   <a href="#">CSS 3</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample to switch class

```
var icon = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons div");
for (var i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) {
  icon[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(this.className.includes("active")){  
      this.classList.remove("active");
    } else {    
      this.classList.add("active");
    }    
  });
}
```

Here is the working jsfiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/88pd6zj0/3/

Comment: thank's, but how switch classes - if we push first button - should be solid button, if we push next button - first class should be dashed and second solid.

Comment: pls see the upadted jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/88pd6zj0/3/